# How do i make a token expire time

Tags: php, token

I currently have functions to generate a token, but how would i go about making it expire?Also, what would be a good shelf-life for the token?

Token Generation code:

```
function token($length = 40) {
    $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    $charactersLength = strlen($characters);
    $token = 12000;
    $token = srand(floor(time() / $token));
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $token .= $characters[rand(0, $charactersLength - 1)];
    }
    return $token;
}
```

Comment: read RFC  for best practices https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7519

Comment: `return $token . "_"  . (time() + 60 * 30)`

Comment: this function have not problem i want only expire token after 30 minutes

Comment: I have to go with @Dimi on this one jwt is the best way to go (http://jwt.io).

Comment: Where are you save the token? in db? add col to db and set the expire  token date.

Comment: no need to save token on db, simple say me what number do I change with 12000 Which is 30 minutes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best practice is to have a database table that stores the information of tokens created...

```
id | expiry_timestamp | token ...
```

Then edit the code to store each token created with its expiry_timestamp...

```
function token($length = 40, $expiry) {
    // Set expiry_timestamp..
    $expiry_timestamp = time() + $expiry;

    // Generate the token...
    $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    $charactersLength = strlen($characters);
    $token = 12000;
    $token = srand(floor(time() / $token));
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $token .= $characters[rand(0, $charactersLength - 1)];
    }

    /** Do a quick manipulation in the token table...
    * ...Connect to database table then execute following SQL statement..
    * mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO token_table (token, expiry_timestamp) VALUES($token, $expiry_timestamp)");
    */

    return array($token,$expiry);
}
```

Just incase you want to check if it has expired, you can use another function to fetch its expiry_timestamp and confirm whether or not, it is greater than the current timestamp

Comment: thanks, just what is this `$token = 12000;`  i want expir token after 30 minutes